# displaying webpage from python http sever gives Ã¯Â»Â¿

Tags: python, html

My goal is to make a simple web server for my home network that I can use to store files on, allowing me keep rarely used files off of my computer and then just download them when I need them. Right now i'm still working on displaying the html pages. I figured out how to display one called "upload.html" and one called "index.html". However I have a page called "dataSync.html" the browser just displays all the text of the html file with "Ã¯Â»Â¿" in front of it. These webpages are not the final webpages, they are just test so I can get the python server working before I make the webpage. "dataSync.html" was actually my fist webpage and was for testing purposes only.

Here is the python code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import os


class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

def __set_headers__(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
    self.end_headers()

def do_HEAD(self):
    self.__set_headers__()

def do_GET(self):
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    try:
        if self.path.endswith('.html'):
            f = open(dir_path + self.path)  # open requested file

            # send code 200 response
            self.send_response(200)

            # send header first
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text-html')
            self.end_headers()

            # send file content to client
            self.wfile.write(f.read().encode('utf-8'))
            f.close()
            return

    except IOError:
        self.send_error(404, 'file not found')


 def main():
    try:
    httpserver = HTTPServer(('', 8888), MyHandler)
    print('started httpserver...')
    httpserver.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('^C received, shutting down server')
    httpserver.socket.close()


 if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Index Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Our Funky HTML Page</title>
<meta name="description" content="Our first page">
<meta name="keywords" content="html tutorial template">
</head>
<body>
Content goes here.
</body>
</html>
```

DataSynce Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Data Sync</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="data sync.css">
<script>
function hide() {
document.getElementById("text").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>
<script>
function show() {
document.getElementById("text").style.visibility = "visible";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Data Sync</h1>
<p>Here you will be able to sync your data between two computers</p>
<img src="https://qbservices.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/quickbooks-sync-
300x94.jpg">
<p id="text">click the button to change this text</p>
<button id="button1" onclick="hide()">Hide</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="show()">Show</button>
<button id="FolderButton" 
onClick="document.querySelector('.inputFile').click();">Folder</button>
<input class="inputFile" type="file" accept=".dir" style="display: none" 
webkitdirectory directory multiple/>
</body>
</html>
```

The dataSync.html does work outside of python
Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: `text-html` isn’t the right `Content-Type`. Use `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. This did solve the problem. However, I still get "Ã¯Â»Â¿"  at the very top of the webpage. Do you know why. Google didn't give much of an answer.

Comment: Make sure your file is saved as UTF-8, and pass that to `open`: `open(dir_path + self.path, encoding="utf-8")`.

Comment: So I did what you suggested, the files is saved with 'utf-8' and I added that to the open function. It did not make a difference though. However, I added to the html file too and it took away the strange characters, so thank you for that :)